# View all Nodes & Comments by logged in user

Tags: views, 8

Is it possible to show all comments and nodes created by a logged in user in one view?

Would like to display fields. Show title and time stamp when the node OR comment was created.

Another challenge is that I would like to sort by the newest Node / Comment. This is a little confusing for me since we are dealing with two different type of entities.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it in one view. Follow below steps

1. Create page view
2. Add the title and comment field
3. Add author by field with choose the radio button *Provide default value* then *Type - User ID from logged in user * in contextual filter
4. Add last update filed comment time field in sorting then add another one for node created time stamp.

It will resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately it did not work. Can you provide some more details?

Comment: @progonat what's are you facing? I will export the view article and share here

Comment: That would be great. Nodes were grouped together. Comments together. Where I wanted to show the Node title for Nodes the logged in user had commented on. Also show the titles for nodes that the logged is user had created. Sorting by data of Node or comment didn't work either.